# Printing PDF from windows service on windows 7 machine

Tags: pdf, printing, windows-services, windows-7-x64

I am having a problem with printing PDF files from Windows Service.

The Windows service has the following meta code:

> - System.Process process = new Process();
> - assign file path
> - assign verb = "print"
> - CreateNoWindow set to true
> - WindowStyle set to hidden
> - process.start()

I built the Windows Service and installed on Windows XP as User Account and it works fine.
But when I install the same thing on Windows 7 Enterprise, it no longer prints ( although it  installs properly)

Does anyone have any idea what the problem would be?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 there might be additional policy settings preventing services from opening background processes. Generally, I'd recommend looking into Aspose.PDF, PDFTron or FoxIt SDK, to print from a service.

Comment: Another thought ... In WinXP printers are shared between the users. I vaguely recall this might not be the case in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP your service is running in a "regular", login-enabled Session 0, but on Windows 7 [Session 0 is Isolated](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) and using the shell to print may not function as expected there.

What application is printing your PDFs? Can you invoke it directly, passing the file to print on the command line?

Comment: The process directly invokes the 'default' software for that PDF and gives the 'print' command.
Eg: If 'Foxit' Reader is the default software for PDF's, then that is invoked and given the print command.

Comment: Actually, no. Your process invokes the Windows shell, which then should invoke the default software as you describe. However, with Session 0 Isolation there is no Explorer in Session 0 and your calls to invoke the shell may yield unexpected results. I suggest that you try invoking Foxit directly in your Process object like this: "<full-path-to-Foxit-Reader.exe>" /p <pdf-file>